# How to tell jq to print multiples fields(keys) from aws ec2 cli

Tags: json, amazon-ec2, jq

running aws ec2 describe-instances will return a json text similar to the following:

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Instances": [
                  "PublicDnsName": "ec2..."
                    "VpcId": "vpc-...",
                        ...
            "Instances": [
```

I know for each "Instance" I can extract the contents of a single field, for example PublicDnsName, using jq as follows:
`jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName'` which will list the dns names for my instances
But how do I extract two or more fields and separate them by a space or comma or something? I want PublicDnsName and VpcId to be listed side-by-side for each Instance.

Specifically what I'm looking for is a list of instances where VpcId is null, undefined, or non-existent. In other words I'd like a list of my Classic instances and I need this through api so I can process the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Working with AWS CLI alone

I love jq and it's really really helpful to combine with aws cli but you can already do a lot simply with aws cli in your case.

> But how do I extract two or more fields and separate them by a space or comma or something? I want PublicDnsName and VpcId to be listed side-by-side for each Instance.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query '
  Reservations[*].Instances[].{PublicDnsName:PublicDnsName,VpcId:VpcId}' --output text
```

> Specifically what I'm looking for is a list of instances where VpcId is null, undefined, or non-existent

If you search for empty VpcId, the following will work:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query '
  Reservations[].Instances[?VpcId==``].[PublicDnsName]' --output text
```

## Working with `jq`

As the original question is

> How to tell jq to print multiples fields(keys) from aws ec2 cli

sure you can work with `jq`, you can get multiple fields with the following by separating by a comma

```
aws ec2 describe-instances |\
  jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].PublicDnsName, .Reservations[].Instances[].VpcId'
```

You can better write it by factoring `Reservations[].Instances`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances |\
  jq '.Reservations[].Instances[] | .PublicDnsName, .VpcId'
```

and jq supports transformation into csv but it needs to take an array and to avoid issues with double-quotes, you can work with raw data:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances |\
  jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[]
         | [.PublicDnsName, .VpcId]
         | @csv'
```

The last will just product the expected result:

```
"ec2-some_id_region.amazonaws.com","vpc-some_other_id"
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Factoring it through `| .PublicDnsName, .VpcId` works for me.

Comment: Another useful variation:

`aws ec2 describe-instances |  jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | [.PrivateDnsName, .VpcId, .PublicDnsName]|@tsv'`